# figure/table caption formatting without packages

Tags: formatting, captions

I am writing a document which needs to have tables and figures.

Normally for formatting the caption of figures/tables I use

```
\renewcommand{\@makecaption}
```

But it affects both tables and figures captions.

Is there any way to define different formatting for captions, e.g. bold captions for tables and italic captions for figures? I'd like to do this without using packages.

Comment: Why is using a package not an option for you?

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann, there is no reason not using packages, i just want to find out if there is any private command or direct method for that! thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the **caption** package is more friendly, as it allows for setting captions for figures and tables differently out of the box.

If you really don't want to use packages (I can't see why), then

```
\newcommand{\@maketablecaption}{...}
\newcommand{\@makefigurecaption}{...}
\toks@=\expandafter{\table}
\edef\table{\let\noexpand\@makecaption\noexpand\@maketablecaption\the\toks@}
\toks@=\expandafter{\figure}
\edef\figure{\let\noexpand\@makecaption\noexpand\@makefigurecaption\the\toks@}
```

where `\@maketablecaption` and `\@makefigurecaption` are defined as it suits you.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for! Thanks