# Legend and caption label of graph

Tags: pgfplots

I add 4 legend to my graph and different types of mark. Also, I want the legends to be under the X axis and in one line to each other. Position of legend
Also How I can to write caption of this graph: Figure 1. Growth of different types foodborne pathogens.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
color=black,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=24,
%xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
xtick={0,4,8,12,24}, %%%<------------- here
xlabel=\ {Time},
ymin=0,
ymax=10,
ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
ylabel=\ {log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
y axis line style={black},
ytick style={black},
yticklabel style={black},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,    
tick align = outside,]
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=0.5pt,
mark size=2.5pt,
mark size=2.5pt,
mark=square*,
mark options={solid,fill=white}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 5\\
4 5\\
8 9.8\\
12 8.8\\
24 8.62\\};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=0.5pt,
mark size=2.5pt,
mark size=2.5pt,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=white}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 2\\
4 3\\
8 4.8\\
12 7.8\\
24 8.162\\};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=0.5pt,
mark size=2.5pt,
mark size=2.5pt,
mark=halfdiamond*,
mark options={solid,fill=white}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 3\\
4 1\\
8 2.8\\
12 2.8\\
24 2.162\\};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=0.5pt,
mark size=2.5pt,
mark size=2.5pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,fill=white}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 4\\
4 3.3\\
8 5.8\\
12 5.7\\
24 6.162\\};
\legend {$Staphylococcus\ aureus$, $Escherichia\ coli$,$Listeria\ monocytogenes$,$Campylobacter\ jejuni$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Also, Figure end only one dot, Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The Plots with Standard Caption

Something like this? I've included code to display the legend in one line but I've commented it because I'm not sure that is really what you mean. (It looks silly to me as the legend is then much wider than the plots!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      color=black,
      scale only axis,
      xmin=0,
      xmax=24,
      %xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
      xtick={0,4,8,12,24}, %%%<------------- here
      xlabel=\ {Time},
      ymin=0,
      ymax=10,
      ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
      yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
      ylabel=\ {log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
      y axis line style={black},
      ytick style={black},
      yticklabel style={black},
      axis x line*=bottom,
      axis y line*=left,
      tick align = outside,
      every axis legend/.append style={
        at = {(.5,-.2)},
        anchor = north,
%       legend columns=-1, % to display legends in one line but do you really want this?
        legend cell align = left,
        draw = none,
        legend columns = 2,
      },
    ]
      \addplot [
        color=black,
        solid,
        line width=0.5pt,
        mark size=2.5pt,
        mark size=2.5pt,
        mark=square*,
        mark options={solid,fill=white}
      ]
      table[row sep=crcr]{
        0 5\\
        4 5\\
        8 9.8\\
        12 8.8\\
        24 8.62\\};
      \addplot [
        color=black,
        solid,
        line width=0.5pt,
        mark size=2.5pt,
        mark size=2.5pt,
        mark=*,
        mark options={solid,fill=white}]
      table[row sep=crcr]{
        0 2\\
        4 3\\
        8 4.8\\
        12 7.8\\
        24 8.162\\};
      \addplot [
        color=black,
        solid,
        line width=0.5pt,
        mark size=2.5pt,
        mark size=2.5pt,
        mark=halfdiamond*,
        mark options={solid,fill=white}]
      table[row sep=crcr]{
        0 3\\
        4 1\\
        8 2.8\\
        12 2.8\\
        24 2.162\\};
      \addplot [
        color=black,
        solid,
        line width=0.5pt,
        mark size=2.5pt,
        mark size=2.5pt,
        mark=triangle*,
        mark options={solid,fill=white}]
      table[row sep=crcr]{
        0 4\\
        4 3.3\\
        8 5.8\\
        12 5.7\\
        24 6.162\\};
      \legend {$Staphylococcus\ aureus$, $Escherichia\ coli$,$Listeria\ monocytogenes$,$Campylobacter\ jejuni$}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Growth of different types foodborne pathogens.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: adjusted legend and added caption]

## Formatting the Caption

Based on [Andreas Wallner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56050/), adding

```
\usepackage{caption}
  \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{fullstop}{.\quad}
  \captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=fullstop}
```

to your preamble will modify the formatting of figure captions accordingly:

[image: caption adjustment]

## Adjusting the Size

You can adjust the size of your plots using

```
\pgfplotsset{width=120mm}
```

[image: adjusted plot size on page]

Comment: Thank you very much dear,    Only one small question- how do legends will be 2 name legend and inside 2 name of legend, without black border total legends

Comment: @user67733 Sorry, but what do you mean by 'do legends will be 2 name legend and inside 2 name of legend'?

Comment: @user67733 You can add `draw = none, legend columns = 2,` to the legend style if you don't want the border and you want 2 columns. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I send hand-draw photoshop picture

Comment: @user67733 The code I just suggested will do that. Just add those lines to modify the legend style.

Comment: @user67733 I've added that information to my answer (see edited code above). Formatting of the 'Figure:` is a separate issue which will depend on your class etc. That is, it has nothing to do with `pgfplots` and should be a different question if it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @user67733 For the figure captions, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56050/ or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30679/, for example, but note that this depends on your class and the other packages you are loading.

Comment: That mean I can not delete duoble dot-only one dot for exmple Figure 1.   /// Also How I can increase zoom - or size of my graph. Thank you very much

Comment: @user67733 See edit. I don't know what you mean by 'cannot delete double dot-only one dot for example Figure 1.///'. I've shown how to alter the caption format and size of your plot. As best I can make out, that's what you are trying to do?

Comment: @user67733 Please consider accepting my answer if the solutions are satisfactory. This helps show other users that the question has an answer and helps people find solutions more easily, as well as showing people which questions still need answering. (Disclaimer: I will get points. Caveat: So will you ;).)

Comment: Thank you dear . You answer my question , I am satisfactory. Also you can answer my end question : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217981/mirror-symmetry        I think for you this is no problem, again thank you very much

Comment: @user67733 The way to say 'thanks' is to ***accept*** or vote up answers. You cannot vote things up at the moment as you do not have enough reputation. But you can accept answers. If my answer really did answer your question, as you say, then you should accept it.

Comment: @user67733 Your other question is not answerable in its current form, as people have explained to you in comments.

Comment: Where my question not answerable

Comment: @user67733 [This explains the problem.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217981/mirror-symmetry#comment511055_217981)

Comment: Ok. But I need to connect . respect

Comment: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=25428